# CoordinatorLayout (Toolbar+NestedScrollView+BottomNavigationView) issue

Tags: android, toolbar, android-nestedscrollview, android-navigation-bar

I Am using CoordinatorLayout as root layout in that am showing the Toolbar, NestedScrollView and BottomNavigationView. I have designed well but the NestedScrollView is not comes under the Toolbar, it's started behind the Toolbar.

I am using the below XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity.DashBoard_Activity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="8">

    <include
        layout="@layout/actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2.8">
        // Scroll View
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="3">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                app:layout_behavior="com.evs.demo.layout.FixedScrollingViewBehavior"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@color/chartlayoutBgcolor"
                    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

                    // Home and save button //
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/topbarColor"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="4">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_home" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_save" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    // First chart //
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="256dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">


                        <com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.HIChartView
                            android:id="@+id/hc"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/hc"
                            android:gravity="right">


                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                android:id="@+id/Day7"
                                android:layout_width="26dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                                android:text="7D"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Border1"
                                android:padding="1dp"/>

                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                android:id="@+id/Border1"
                                android:layout_width="1dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Day14"
                                android:padding="1dp"
                                android:background="@color/lineOrange"/>


                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                android:id="@+id/Day14"
                                android:layout_width="26dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                                android:text="14D"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Border2"
                                android:padding="1dp"/>


                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                android:id="@+id/Border2"
                                android:layout_width="1dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Day21"
                                android:padding="1dp"
                                android:background="@color/lineOrange"/>


                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                android:id="@+id/Day21"
                                android:layout_width="26dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                                android:text="21D"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:padding="1dp"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    // Second chart //
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="256dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                        <com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.HIChartView
                            android:id="@+id/hc1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    // Last label //
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="(To normalize weekday trend, Prior year = Current day-364 Example Monday VS Monday last year) "
                            android:textColor="@color/lineGreen"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/graphText"
                            android:lines="2"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


    // for menu view
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:background="@color/chartlayoutBgcolor"
        android:id="@+id/infoAct"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Data details"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:background="@color/chartlayoutBgcolor"
            android:textColor="@color/lineBlue"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Max Data Date: NOV - 10"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:background="@color/chartlayoutBgcolor"
            android:textColor="@color/lineBlue"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Refresh Date : Nov - 11"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:background="@color/chartlayoutBgcolor"
            android:textColor="@color/lineBlue"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    // Buttom Bar Buttons

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/lineGray"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>


</LinearLayout>
```

For tool bar Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/lineGray"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0.0px"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="5dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="5dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="5dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="5dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="5dp"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="6">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1.1"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/watch" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.7">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:text="Thu,25 - Sep"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:text="Current"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:text="123"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/lineBlue"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:text="321"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:text="7dma"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="11dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:text="PriorYR"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:text="123"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/lineBlue"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:text="321"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:text="7dma"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="11dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:text="Healthscore"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:text="123"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/lineBlue"
                    android:textSize="13dp"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:text="321"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:text="7dma"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="11dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Since am new to Android I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: you can set `margin_top` to your linear layout to `?attr/actionBarSize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have set your toolbar height to `80dp` explicitly, Set top margin of linear layout below toolbar to `80dp` as well.

```
android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
```

Change your layout as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".Activity.DashBoard_Activity"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        layout="@layout/actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2.8">
        // Scroll View
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="3">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                app:layout_behavior="com.evs.demo.layout.FixedScrollingViewBehavior"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@color/chartlayoutBgcolor"
                    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

                    // Home and save button //
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/topbarColor"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="4">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_home" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_save" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    // First chart //
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="256dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">


                        <com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.HIChartView
                            android:id="@+id/hc"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/hc"
                            android:gravity="right">


                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                android:id="@+id/Day7"
                                android:layout_width="26dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                                android:text="7D"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Border1"
                                android:padding="1dp"/>

                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                android:id="@+id/Border1"
                                android:layout_width="1dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Day14"
                                android:padding="1dp"
                                android:background="@color/lineOrange"/>


                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                android:id="@+id/Day14"
                                android:layout_width="26dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                                android:text="14D"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Border2"
                                android:padding="1dp"/>


                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                android:id="@+id/Border2"
                                android:layout_width="1dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Day21"
                                android:padding="1dp"
                                android:background="@color/lineOrange"/>


                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                android:id="@+id/Day21"
                                android:layout_width="26dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                                android:text="21D"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:padding="1dp"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    // Second chart //
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="256dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                        <com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.HIChartView
                            android:id="@+id/hc1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    // Last label //
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="(To normalize weekday trend, Prior year = Current day-364 Example Monday VS Monday last year) "
                            android:textColor="@color/lineGreen"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/graphText"
                            android:lines="2"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


    // for menu view
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:background="@color/chartlayoutBgcolor"
        android:id="@+id/infoAct"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Data details"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:background="@color/chartlayoutBgcolor"
            android:textColor="@color/lineBlue"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Max Data Date: NOV - 10"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:background="@color/chartlayoutBgcolor"
            android:textColor="@color/lineBlue"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Refresh Date : Nov - 11"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:background="@color/chartlayoutBgcolor"
            android:textColor="@color/lineBlue"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    // Buttom Bar Buttons
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/lineGray"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes scrollview comes down but not fully under ToolBar

Comment: can you post your code for separate xml you have included for toolbar.

Comment: Sure, Posted the toolbar xml

Comment: you have set explicit height of 80dp to your toolbar, so you need to set margin_top to 80dp inplace of default value I have used in answer.

Comment: great, It comes good now but NestedScrollView is not scrolling now

Comment: In fact it was worked before without BottomNavigationView

Comment: after adding the BottomNavigationView I have changed the root as CoordinatorLayout and then its not working

Comment: there is no specific need to use coordinator layout as root with BottomNavigationView  you can use other layout with it.

Comment: If I change that BottomNavigationView will not display

Comment: it will be visible, set parent layout_height to 0dp and set weight to 1, now set bottomnavigationview height to wrap content and it will be visible. set parent layout to linear layout inplace of coordinator layout.

Comment: Yeah its visible but its not attached to the bottom, its displaying below to the ToolBar

Comment: Thank you very much its scrolling now, But still the last label LinearLayout  is not showing on the screen. It hiding behind the BottomNavigationView

Comment: Have removed the margin of the parent Linear layout

Comment: I don't have library for HIChartView so I have just used textview when I was editing. you need to tweak some values as you need.

Comment: No After the second chart am showing the one more linear layout its not showing

Comment: remove weightsum 2.8 line and try.

Comment: When I click on the BottomNavigationView item have to show the Linear layout as a drawer if I show that it hiding the overall layout. Can you please tell me how to achieve that ?

Comment: You can see the code in that I have mentioned "// for menu" view right? Its for the BottomNavigationView clickable item. I can able to show that view but its hides NestedScrollView and BottomNavigationView

Comment: you can ask separate question as it will be not helpful here. If previous solution worked you can mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for you time am going to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the scroll behavior to the root LinearLayout, just use the code below and wrap your toolbar container with AppBarLayout if it hasn`t been done

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".Activity.DashBoard_Activity"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="8">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            >

            <include
                layout="@layout/actionbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="com.evs.demo.layout.FixedScrollingViewBehavior"
                android:weightSum="2.8">

                // Scroll View
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="3">

                    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fillViewport="true"
                        android:isScrollContainer="true">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:background="@color/chartlayoutBgcolor"
                            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

                            // Home and save button //
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="34dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:background="@color/topbarColor"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:weightSum="4">

                                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_home" />

                                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_save" />

                                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                            // First chart //
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="256dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="0dp">


                                <com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.HIChartView
                                    android:id="@+id/hc"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                                <RelativeLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/hc"
                                    android:gravity="right">


                                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                        android:id="@+id/Day7"
                                        android:layout_width="26dp"
                                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                                        android:text="7D"
                                        android:textSize="10sp"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Border1"
                                        android:padding="1dp"/>

                                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                        android:id="@+id/Border1"
                                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Day14"
                                        android:padding="1dp"
                                        android:background="@color/lineOrange"/>


                                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                        android:id="@+id/Day14"
                                        android:layout_width="26dp"
                                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                                        android:text="14D"
                                        android:textSize="10sp"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Border2"
                                        android:padding="1dp"/>


                                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                        android:id="@+id/Border2"
                                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Day21"
                                        android:padding="1dp"
                                        android:background="@color/lineOrange"/>


                                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                        android:id="@+id/Day21"
                                        android:layout_width="26dp"
                                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                                        android:text="21D"
                                        android:textSize="10sp"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                        android:padding="1dp"/>

                                </RelativeLayout>

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            // Second chart //
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="256dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                                <com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.HIChartView
                                    android:id="@+id/hc1"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            // Last label //
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:text="(To normalize weekday trend, Prior year = Current day-364 Example Monday VS Monday last year) "
                                    android:textColor="@color/lineGreen"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/graphText"
                                    android:lines="2"/>
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>


                    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

                 </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


            // Buttom Bar Buttons

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigationBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/lineGray"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">

             </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```